# Counting particular words

Tags: python, string, list, function, sum

I'm working on a function that can count the number of words (including contractions like couldn't) in a list having exactly five letters.

I searched the internet for a similar issue but came up empty-handed.

```
def word_count(wlist):
    """ This function counts the number of words (including contractions like couldn't) in a list w/ exactly 5
        letters."""
    w = 0
    for word in x:
        w += 1 if len(word) == 5 else 0
    return w

x = ["adsfe", "as", "jkiejjl", "jsengd'e", "jjies"]    
print(word_count(x))
```

I'd like this function to count the number of words (including contractions like couldn't) in a list w/ exactly five letters. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: My original post is edited to reflect the issue about a duplicate topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def word5(wlist):
...     return len([word for word in wlist if len(word)==5])
...
>>> word5(["adsfe", "as", "jkiejjl", "jseke", "jjies"])
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with filter:

```
wordlist = ["adsfe", "as", "jkiejjl", "jseke", "jjies"]
len(list(filter(lambda x: len(x)==5, wordlist)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing answer that doesn't involve list comprehension in case it may be easier to understand.

```
def word5(wlist):
    cnt=0
    for word in wordList:
        cnt += 1 if len(word) == 5 else 0
    return cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
w5 = list(map(len,wordlist)).count(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

A compact alternative with a smaller memory-footprint:

```
def word5(wlist, n=5):
    return sum((1 for word in wlist if len(word) == n))
```

This also works but is about 2.5 times slower:

```
def word5(wlist, n=5):
    return sum((int(len(word) == n) for word in wlist))
```